# HtmlAgilityPack td.innertext bug?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, html-agility-pack

I'm building some tables from data in our databases.  It is from a lot of international sources so I was having encoding issues and I think I got them all cleared up.  But now I'm seeing some strange output and can't figure out why.

This is a C# app in VS2010.  Running in Debug, I see the string in my class begins:

```
Animal and vegetable oils  1 < 5 MW <br>5-50 MW  30 <br>
```

But when I assign with:

```
td = htmlDoc.CreateElement("td");
td.Attributes.Add("rowspan", "5");
td.Attributes.Add("valign", "top");
td.InnerHtml = this.DRGuideNote.ToString();
```

The td.InnerHtml shows

```
Animal and vegetable oils  1 < 5=\"\" mw=\"\"><br>5-50 MW  30 <br>
```

Why is it putting the equals and escaped quotes into that text??? It doesn't do it across all the data, just a few files.  Any ideas?  (PS. There are html breaks in the strings not showing up, how do I post so it ignores html?  Tried the "indent with 4 spaces but didn't seem to work?)

Comment: The `<` in `1 < 5` is incorrect HTML. Change it to `1 &lt; 5` and it should work.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that and you're right I should be encoding for html.  But the output is showing up correctly everywhere else.  The issue is that I'm getting is the added '=""' that shows up after words in my text.  Do you see any reason that would be related?

Comment: After I wrote that, I think I realized what is happening.  Because the < is not encoded, it probably assumes it is the beginning of a tag and then parses each word expecting them to be a parameter without a values, which is why I'm getting the ="", because as far as it is concerned the word is a blank tag param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Agility Pack's HTML parser is treating the `<` as the opening character of an HTML tag. So when it parses the 5 and the MW, it thinks it's inside a tag, and so it is treating them as tag attributes. This treatment stops once it runs into the `<br>` which forces it to close the tag.

The reason it works in browsers is because browsers generally follow the HTML5 spec for handling invalid HTML. The spec has a lot of rules for how to handle invalid HTML, with the goal of making sense of what the intent was. In this situation the spec says that a carat followed by a space should just be treated as text. HAP's parser doesn't deal with this particular edge case. So I wouldn't say this is a bug, so much as a limitation of HAP's native HTML parser.

An alternative to HAP is [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/csquery) ([nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/)) which uses a complete HTML5 parser (the same HTML parser as Firefox in fact), and can handle this kind of markup.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what was happening.  I've been jumping through hoops trying to end up with quality output data coming from often flawed data stored given to us in spreadsheets, sometimes htmlencoded, sometimes not, full of weird characters because it is international.  Now I'm just missing the obvious stuff haha.  Thanks.